# How to determine which object to create in a factory pattern

Tags: oop, design-patterns, factory, factory-pattern

I'm creating an autocomplete functionality from scratch using Angular 2. I need to listen for different keystrokes and perform a different action depending on what keystroke is pressed. There are four types of keystrokes I must listen for: an enter press, a down arrow press, an up arrow press, and a key press that would fire a new autocomplete query (ex: backspace, alphanumeric keys, delete, something that changes the value of the string in the input text box).

My project lead wants me to implement a design pattern for creating the keystroke handlers, and recommended the factory pattern (most likely as practice with design patterns). So the theoretical factory would create a different object for each of my four types of keystrokes. The listener gives back a string that I can use to determine which key was pressed (ex "ArrowUp, "ArrowDown", "Enter"). So the enter handler would select the highlighted option and populate it into the text box. A down handler would deselect the current option and select the option below it.

What is the best way for the factory to determine which object to create. For example I could do something like:

```
createHandler(keystroke) {
  //or alternatively use a case statement
  if(keystroke === "Enter") {
    return new EnterHandler();
  } else if(keystroke === "ArrowDown") {
    return new ArrowDownHandler();
  } else if(...)
}
```

But after reading up on this pattern, this is a "naive" implementation. What is the best way to know which object to create based on a string passed in then for my particular case? Or is there another better pattern for the functionality I am looking for?

Answer (score 0):

Your proposed implementation would work fine. It's clean and simple.

A couple of ways you could enhance it would be:

1. Use a dictionary of { String, Handler }
2. Inject the various commands from the Composition Root, instead of have them live inside the factory method
3. Provide Command Objects that that have their own names, and then execute the command with the corresponding name